# How can I troubleshoot my router NOT routing between LAN PCs?

Tags: routing, router, local-area-network

I have a FiOS router, which has 3 PCs connected to it.

One of the PCs used to run several servers/services; that I previously (using a different router from different ISP) successfully connected to in the past: e.g. FTP server on port 2222, RDP on 3389.

Now, when I try to connect to that PC from other PCs on a new router, NONE of the connections work.

PC in question is Windows XP without any firewall software, IP is allocated using DHCP, **router is Verizon FiOS's Actiontech MI424WR-GEN3I**.

Here's what I tried:

- The PC in question connects to Internet successfully (e.g. web browser, chat, etc.. all work)
- The PC in question is visible from the router's network device list, and the IP matches up with the IP shown via `ipconfig /all` on the PC
- The FTP server on the PC in question managed to successfully add itself to port forwarding tables on the router, I see the following rule added: `Serv-U_Auto
  TCP Any -> 2222`
- I tried running `tracert` to that PC from another PC. Says "Request Timed Out"

  - tracert to the router itself works in 1 hop.
  - tracert from the affected PC to other PCs also times out.
- I tried telnetting directly to open ports (2222 and 3389). Times out.
- I even tried ICMP ping test connection feature of the router itself to that PC. That timed out as well, 100% packet loss.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this inability to connect to the PC?

It looks to me as if the router simply stopped routing between the PCs on a LAN, without affecting routing to the WAN internet connection.

But I can't figure out how to verify that in the router's web config software.

Comment: [Windows XP? With no firewall?](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/business/retiring-xp.aspx)

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Firewall was disabled on purpose, to ease troubleshooting.

Comment: Run wireshark on the XP machine and see if you see the packets hitting when you ping or telnet to it.

Comment: `How can I troubleshoot my router NOT routing between LAN PCs?` - Routers don't route traffic between hosts on the same network. Routing has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @joeqwerty - fair enough. The question still stands. Feel free to edit in proper terminology - I'm a software engineer, not a networking expert.

Comment: Start with the basics. Does the computer in question have a good physical connection? Does it have the proper ip address/subnet mask?

Comment: @joeqwerty - yes/yes.

Comment: Try a different port on the router.